# Are 5G signals dangerous?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biology, microwaves, medical-physics

Ive been seeing a lot lately on the dangers of 5g and exposure to the internet and mobile signals but I dont understand why they are considered harmful when the 5g frequency band will be around 25 Ghz. Visible light has a frequency much much greater than this, and I thought how damaging radiation is, depends on its frequency. Ionising radiation is several orders of magnitude greater in frequency.

Just wanted to know if there was any physics behind the 5g signals impact on the human body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How strong are Wi-Fi signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482014/)

Comment: It is worth noting that there are some groups doing a deliberate push of fear about 5G for political reasons https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/12/science/5g-phone-safety-health-russia.html as well as the usual crowd who think new technology is likely to be harmful. That doesn't actually tell us anything about the biophysics that matters, nor does it mean being concerned makes one into a Russian stooge... but it should make us demand rather clear reasoning, data and science from people making claims.

Comment: The frequency is near that of microwave ovens (2450 MHz). The principle concern for microwave ovens is unwanted heating of human tissue and for that reason there safety limits regarding microwave oven leakage leakage. Studies on the possible non thermal effects at these frequencies have been going on for nearly 50 years but as I understand it the general consensus is still that the main concern is for the thermal (heating) effects on tissue.

Comment: For a nice summary of how different electromagnetic frequencies interact with matter check out the Hyperphysics website

Comment: Pull up any data sheet, 4G was already using 700 MHz ~ 2600+ MHz, and there were already some study to show that 3G/4G single may cause issues. I guess the main answer was intensity and susceptibility. It's like saying cola and alcohol may not be a very healthy drink, but weren't you going to drink it anyway? The 5G deployment was delayed around the global so there's no point to talk about it's influence. I mean, it's hard for bio people to do experiments with something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Why was this closed as a dup of the Wi-Fi question? There's a whole litany of scientists who seem to be warning against 5G. See e.g. https://www.emfscientist.org/index.php/emf-scientist-appeal and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29655646